# ssh to a new user in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I created an user in ubuntu and now I want to do ssh with that user. I'm able to do ssh but I'm not getting in the shell:

```
myUserName@myMachineName:path$
```

I just get:

```
$
```

And I don't see the path where I'm standing or been able to get last commands. I'm not sure how is this called or how to look for it on the internet. That's why I prefer to ask here.

[image]

Comment: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/21/customizing-your-bash-command-prompt/

Comment: What is the output of `getent passwd myUserName`?

Comment: @Zoredache I get myUserName:x:502:1001::/home/myUserName:/bin/sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you create the account? Looks like you did something unusual instead of using `adduser username`. I would guess that the home directory didn't get created properly, or /etc/skel didn't get copied over.

Comment: useradd -m <user_name> this is what I used. And the directory was well created.

Comment: Well that is your problem.  `useradd` doesn't copy skel, and gives you a poor choice for a shell.  `/bin/sh` is typically dash and not bash on recent versions of Debian/Ubuntu.  You can delete the user and re-created it using the correct tool, or manually copy your shell, and then fix the shell for that account to /bin/bash.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I deleted the user and created whith: adduser -uid 502 -gid 1001 -shell /usr/bin/bash myUser. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your in a basic shell, you can type `bash` and get a bash shell,

You can change this permanently, assuming you always want to use bash shell after login,

by using `chsh -s /bin/bash`